# Need to Identify SMT Part W267J

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

Need to Identify the Part Below , Try to search & Read Catalogs but still can not Identify it. W267J Need to replace it What is the Model Number?

[image]

Comment: How have you decided that it needs to be replaced? I can't quite tell from the photo, but it looks like there are solder bridges between some of the legs, which would be bad.

Comment: Thank You .. Just for take a photo re solder  it simply. Can you help to find the part  from Internet.

Comment: How have you decided that it needs to be replaced?

Comment: There is a switch connected with this circuit to go forward & Backward. Its Connected with this component. Only that Button is not working. Button signal is Fine.